# Grab all input field values after button click. ( JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This is my first question, hopefully it's formatted correctly.
The idea is that after pressing the #grabValues button, that the input values get stored into an array for calculating the total amount of hours.

I am planning on coding that part in an external js file, as I'm assuming it would need to be loaded in the body, whereas the other needed to be loaded in the head.

Thanks for reading.

```js
console.log('Script has loaded!');
function formMaker(){
  var dayCount;
  var myMonth = document.getElementById('inputMonth').value;
  console.log(myMonth);
  if( myMonth.includes('jan', 'Jan', 'JAN')){
    dayCount = 31;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('feb', 'Feb', 'FEB')){
    dayCount = 28;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('mar', 'Mar', 'MAR')){
    dayCount = 31;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('apr', 'Apr', 'APR')){
    dayCount = 30;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('may', 'May', 'MAY')){
    dayCount = 31;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('jun', 'Jun', 'JUN')){
    dayCount = 30;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('jul', 'Jul', 'JUL')){
    dayCount = 31;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('aug', 'Aug', 'AUG')){
    dayCount = 31;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('sep', 'Sep', 'SEP')){
    dayCount = 30;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('oct', 'Oct', 'OCT')){
    dayCount = 31;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('nov', 'Nov', 'NOV')){
    dayCount = 30;
  } else if ( myMonth.includes('dec', 'Dec', 'DEC')){
    dayCount = 31;
  } else {
    return;
  }

  for(var i=0; i < dayCount; i++){
    // Loop this with dayCounter value.
    var myFormGroup = document.getElementById('myFormGroup');

    var myLabel = document.createElement('label');
    myLabel.for = 'hours';
    myLabel.innerHTML = 'Hours worked:'; // + day/month

    var myInput = document.createElement('input');
    myInput.type = "number";
    // Add class of month for later.
    myInput.className = 'form-control hours ' + myMonth.toString();
    myInput.placeholder = 'amount of hours here:';

    myFormGroup.appendChild(myLabel);
    myFormGroup.appendChild(myInput);

    //Add different id's to each inputfield being created. JQUERY!
    $('#myFormGroup input').attr('id', function(i) {
       return 'hour_inputs'+(i++);
     })
     console.log('Form(s) has/have been made, with different input IDs');
   }
   // End of loop


   /*$("input").blur(function(){
       alert("This input field has lost its focus.");

   });
   */

   console.log('TEST');
};
// End of formMaker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="number/css" href="workhours.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="formbuilder.js"></script>

<title>Work hours</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="section_row_main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Let's calculate the hours you've worked: month here</h2>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="myFormGroup_test">
        <label for='month'>Month:</label>
        <input type='text' class="form-control month" placeholder="enter month" id="inputMonth">
        <button id="formsNow" onclick="formMaker();">Make forms</button>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="myFormGroup">
        <!--  -->
      </div>
      <button id="grabValues">grabValues!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="hourChecker.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This currently returns the value of the first input field when clicked on button:

```
$('#grabValues').click(function() { 
     $("#myFormGroup input[id^='hour_inputs'][type=number]").val();
     console.log($("#myFormGroup input[id^='hour_inputs']").val()); 
});
```

Comment: what is the problem in your code

Comment: My existing code is working, could be better. But the part I have not coded yet is the problem. I can't figure where to start. $('#grabValues').click(function() {
$("#myFormGroup input[id^='hour_inputs'][type=number]").val();
console.log($("#myFormGroup input[id^='hour_inputs']").val());
}); <- only logs the first input.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/hgv56pzg/2/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get all elements with `$.each` function. Try this code.

```
$('#grabValues').click(function() {
    $.each($("#myFormGroup input[id^='hour_inputs'][type=number]"), function( key, value ) {
        console.log(this.value); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This indeed does return all values. Guess I'm going to read about  the JQuery $.each function now. Thanks again!